# Override initialize for StandardError subclass

Tags: ruby, exception

I'd like to keep a reference to an object inside a `StandardError` subclass.

My first instinct was to override `initialize` and assign it (providing an `attr_reader`), thus:

```
  class UnprocessableCardError < StandardError
    attr_reader :card

    def initialize(msg, card = nil)
      @card = card
      super msg
    end
  end
```

Unfortunately this results in `backtrace must be Array of String` when I use `fail`, thus:

```
fail UnprocessableCardError, "Message", card_obj
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you're using this with `fail`?

Comment: @Jordan you were correct in you answer, question updated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to do this:

```
fail UnprocessableCardError, "Message", card_obj
```

The problem is that you're passing three arguments to `fail`, and `fail` expects the third argument, if present, to be the backtrace, which is expected to be an array of strings.

You can still use your exception class, though, like this:

```
fail UnprocessableCardError.new("Message", card_obj)
```

This works as expected:

```
begin
  fail UnprocessableCardError.new("Message", 12345)
rescue UnprocessableCardError => ex
  puts ex.card
end
# => 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

My current less than satisfactory workaround is:

```
  class UnprocessableCardError < StandardError
    attr_reader :card

    def self.with_card(card, msg)
      new(msg).tap do |error|
        error.instance_variable_set :@card, card
      end
    end
  end
```

Which must be called thus:

```
fail UnprocessableCardError.with_card card, 'some reason'
```